# Ардуино не загружает прошивку в чип, выводя ошибку stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00 и т.п. Драйвера установлены

Tags: arduino

Уже долго вожус с этой проблемой. Ардуино китайская плата, чип от Atmel - R3 MEGA328P
Проблема в том, что в самом IDE выбран правильный com порт, но при компиляции выводит ошибку  stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00. Если знаете решение, ответте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Варианты решения:

1. Отключить плату от USB и подключить еще раз. После этого убедиться, что в списке появился новый COM-порт, выбрать его.
2. Взять другой USB-кабель, подключить в другой USB-порт
3. При отправке прошивки в Arduino нажать на ней кнопку reset
4. Отключить от платы все шилды/провода попробовать всё вышеописанное

В вопросах по Arduino желательно указывать еще название варианта платы. А для китайских клонов - модель второй микросхемы (USB-UART адаптера)